# Using Javadocs with Wikispaces

Tags: java, javadoc, wiki

I am working on a team for a class, and we have written a very large amount of code.  Luckily for us, we were diligent in adding javadoc annotations to everything, so we should be able to create the documentation very easily.  For the class however, we are required to have all of our documentation on a wikispace page.

Some of the pages will be javadoc, some of them will be plain text. Is there an easy way to convert javadocs to wiki pages, or embed javadocs into wiki pages?  Thanks!

Comment: I'd doublecheck if your instructor had "Javadoc API reference" in mind when he meant "documentation has to be on Wikispaces". It really doesn't seem at all suitable for that, as opposed to more prose-heavy hypertext.

Comment: He told us we needed to use the javadoc tags, so I assumed he intended for us to use the Javadoc API reference...I can double check

Comment: I'd just ask him about that stating that the javadoc output isn't really easy to import into Wikispaces. Could be it only needs to be linked, or available as a download, or there's a feature of Wikispaces you're missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself, but maybe doxygen(http://www.doxygen.nl/) in conjunction with this tool (https://code.google.com/p/doxy2wiki/) may be able to solve your problem.

Comment: Its a command line utility, but I don't know the syntax, and I can't find and documentation (ironically)

Comment: Looking at the source (https://code.google.com/p/doxy2wiki/source/browse/trunk/MarcelJoachimKloubert.doxy2wiki/Program.cs) it seems like it's expecting 3 arguments: 1 - the path to the doxygen-generated XML file, 2 - the path to the result file, 3 - the title of the page.

Comment: But what is the first command I need to type into the command line?  I figured it would be doxy2wiki arg1 arg2 arg3, but its not...

Comment: I think it's just source code that you need to compile first, before you can run it. It's a C# project for Visual Studio, so you will probably need to download and install that first.